# No routes matches for nested routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have simple web page and i have trouble with routing:

Index.tsx:

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(
  document.getElementById('root') as HTMLElement
);
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HomePage />
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Homepage:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Main/>}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/login" element={<Login/>}>
                    </Route>
                    <Route path="/register" element={<Register/>}>
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
};

export default HomePage;
```

This works as intended -> if user goes to 'www.example.com' `Main` component is rendered, if user goes to 'www.example.com/login Login` component is rendered and so on.

However, inside my `Main` component i also want to use routing:

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <HomePageHeader/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePageFeed/>}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/animal" element={<AnimalSelection/>}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/animal/:id" element={<Animal/>}>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

`Main` component has header for every content, however depending on the route i want to display different things, for `/` some default info, for `/animal` some menu and list of animals, and for `/animal/:id` info of specific animal.

However, when , inside `HomePageFeed` i try to redirect there:

`let history = useNavigate(); history("/animal")`

I get error: `router.ts:11 No routes matched location "/animal"`

What is correct way how to handle routing such as this? Is this corretly used routing?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is to have a single routing inside your application. Keep your routing part inside your `App.js` and share it in all your pages.

If you strictly want it to be in different component. Try wrapping the routes in the `Main.tsx` inside `BrowserRouter` might work. The problem might be because `<Main />` component is not wrapped anywhere inside the `BrowserRouter`. Try like below,

```
const Main = () => {
    return (
        <div className="app">
            <HomePageHeader/>
            <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<HomePageFeed/>}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/animal" element={<AnimalSelection/>}>
                </Route>
                <Route path="/animal/:id" element={<Animal/>}>
                </Route>
            </Routes>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Main;
```

Comment: as far as i am aware you cant have more BrowserRouter elements in app

Comment: Then It is better to have all the routes in single component.